# React-native link is not working properly

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, node-modules

I tried installing and linking react-native sound into my project. However, when I run the following command in my project directory,

```
react-native link react-native-sound
```

the library doesn't link and I get the following result:

```
Scanning 758 folders for symlinks in /Users/MY_USER_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/node_modules
```

I think my node or npm setup is wrong.

Comment: Tried to manually install it? Sometimes `react-native link` or `rnpm link` fails

Comment: How would I manually install it?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, also tried it with an older node version -> nothing.

Answer (score 8):

1- create new file in project root and name it `react-native.config.js`

2- add this code to `react-native.config.js` :

```
    module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'],
  };
```

3- change `['./src/assets/fonts/']` to your fonts path

4- now run `react-native link`

thats it

Answer (score 5):

Ok after some digging, I found the issue.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/14863

Maybe try applying that fix locally, it should work then.

Comment: Oh Cool! How can I apply that fix locally?

Comment: Just install react native locally and patch the file in the PR with my change.

Answer (score 4):

With latest version of react-native-cli, you can just do:

```
npx react-native-asset
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in linking a npm package, I closed the react native android project in android studio (where I was linking the npm repo), It worked fine for me.