# What is react-native link?

Tags: react-native

> What is the purpose of the ***react-native link*** command?

Comment: check this link and get your answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/56438398/11345701](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56438398/11345701)

Answer (score 106):

> **Note:** from React-Native `0.60.0` linking packages using `react-native link` has become redundant. Autolink has been added to the React-Native CLI which means that iOS will now use cocoapods and Android will use gradle. You can read more about Autolinking [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md).

## What is `react-native link`?

`react-native link` is an automatic way for installing native dependencies. It is an alternative to manually linking the dependency in your project. It works for both Android and iOS.

When linking a project manually the majority of the steps are the same and so using `react-native link` allows you to install the native dependency with less fuss and without having to type similar code or perform similar actions repeatedly.

However, it should be noted that running `react-native link` will not always link a package fully, sometimes additional steps are required and you **should check** carefully with the installation instructions.

**Always read the instructions carefully before installing a dependency and linking it.**

---

#### iOS Considerations

If your project is using **CocoaPods** and the dependency that you are linking has a `.podspec` then when you use run `react-native link` it will update your `Podfile`. This is instead of adding the files directly to your Xcode project. You will also have to run `pod install` inside your `ios` directory otherwise the native dependency won't be fully installed.

Sometimes installing using `CocoaPods` can cause more issues, and not every dependency needs to be installed with `CocoaPods` you could always follow the steps that I outlined in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54696156/5508175) to stop `react-native link` adding a dependency to the `Podfile`, it is not ideal but it is a workaround. Some dependencies require additions to be made to the `Podfile`, so you should only do this if the dependency doesn't require `pods` to run.

---

#### `react-native link` or `react-native link dependency-name`

Should you just use `react-native link` when linking any dependency or should you be more explicit and use `react-native link dependency-name`?

From my experience it is better to use `react-native link dependency-name`. This is due to the fact that `react-native link` will try to link (or re-link) all the dependencies that can be linked and this can lead to code duplication. Most of the issues that I have experienced have been when the Android native dependency is being linked. I think there has been some headway in stopping this from happening in subsequent updates, but the old adage applies here *once bitten, twice shy*

---

#### Linking good practice

When using `react-native link dependency-name` you should follow good practice so that you don't get stung. Sometimes dependencies that you try don't work as expected and removing all the code that was added during the linking process can be tricky. (Xcode project files can be a nightmare to go through if you are unfamiliar with them).

This is how I install dependencies and then link them.

1. Make sure that you are using version control, like `git`.
2. Make sure your code is fully committed with no unsaved changes.
3. Create a new branch, and check it out.
4. Install your dependency `npm i dependency-name`
5. Then link you dependency `react-native link dependency-name`
6. Perform any additional installation steps that the dependency requires. See the installation instructions for the dependency.
7. Check that your code works with the new dependency.
8. `commmit` changes and merge the branch.

---

#### Manual Linking

If you prefer to link your native dependencies manually then you should either follow the instructions on the dependency's website or you can look at the documentation that react-native provides.

Currently there is only an explanation on how to manually link [iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking) projects.

Manually linking `Android` requires you to make changes in the following locations:

1. `settings.gradle`
2. `app/build.gradle`
3. `MainApplication.java`

As always for the exact changes that you should make you should look at the dependency's manual linking instructions.

---

## Do I have to link?

It depends on the dependency that you are using some dependencies use only code written in Javascript, so it is not required to link them, and there is no benefit served by running `react-native link dependency-name`.

However, if the dependency contains **native code** then you will have to link. Either manually or by using `react-native link dependency-name`.

### How can I tell if I need to link the dependency?

Firstly you need to check the website, the github repo, or the npmjs.com page for the dependency. There will usually be instructions there telling you whether to link the dependency after you have installed it.

If you cannot find any instructions about linking, you (probably) won't need to link it.

If you are still unsure, check with the dependency maintainer.

### Can I just run link anyway?

Yes, you can it won't do anything if there is nothing to link. But always run it with `react-native link dependency-name` to avoid issues.

### When do I run link?

You only run it after you have installed your dependency. I would recommend running it just after you have installed the dependency. You should then check to make sure that it works, before installing any new dependencies so that you can easily debug.

You shouldn't need to run it more than once per dependency.

It doesn't matter how many components or changes to the javascript code that you make it won't affect the linking, as the linking is purely native and components are javascript.

---

## What is autolink?

Autolink is a new feature that is being added to the `react-native-cli`. You can read more about autolink [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md).

`Autolink` replaces `react-native-link`

> Autolinking is a mechanism built into CLI that allows adding a
>   dependency with native components for React Native to be as simple as:
>
> `yarn add react-native-webview`
>
> *Autolinking is a replacement for react-native link that brings new features (such as ability to easily integrate native dependencies on iOS) and fixes some of the long-standing issues.*

Once it is fully implemented it should make adding dependencies with native-code to your project much easier.

Comment: Why doesn't `react-native link` run `pod install` by itself if it changes the `Podfile`?

Comment: I don’t actually know. I would suggest taking it up with the dependency [maintainers](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cli) perhaps open an issue with a feature request.

Comment: What happens if other users clone the repository. Is that dependency still linked or they need to run the link command again ? If that's the case, can we simple add a "postinstall" script that runs `react-native link [dependency-name]` every time `npm install` is run ?

Comment: If you have committed the linked code to your repo then it will remain linked. Linking only needs to be performed after the first installation. I don't see why you couldn't add a post install script if you want.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. I don't understand where the link is located. Usually a npm link create a symlink under the node_modules folder but usually that's not under version control. Is that different with react-native link ?

Comment: The `react-native link` adds code to  native iOS and Android parts of your react native project. It doesn’t make any changes to your `node_modules` folder

Comment: @Andrew I see now. Thank you

Comment: Is configurable the way a package is linked? I found a package that, when linked, the imported class in the import sentence is different than the class used inside getPackages() method. So it fails to build.

Comment: The question is a million-dollar-question. But the answer is worth a few million.Especially the `How can I tell if I need to link the dependency?` part

Comment: if I got

    react-native link react-native-live-stream
error: unknown command 'link'

Comment: @VasylPetrov `react-native link` should no longer be used, it should only be used with react-native versions that are less than 0.60.  The current version of react-native is 0.72. `react-native-live-stream` has not been updated in 4 years, so it may no longer be compatible with the current version of react-native. I would suggest reaching out to the repository owner for help, or you can always fork their repo and make the necessary changes so that you can use it with `autolink`.

Answer (score 8):

Linking native library means that you are going to integrate already implemented module into your application or module which completes your react native's module functionality.

Steps to integrate lib(android):

1) Add package name to new packages() 2) Add dependencies to settings.gradle file and main application's gradle i.e app/gradle file. 3) sync the projects gradle because you made changes in the gradle and it's done.

All manual steps like below you have to perform

```
1) Go to your project's home dir using cmd. 
2) run npm install 
3) Thereafter run rnpm link or react-native link 
4) see ios folder in your project folder and if you find any pod file then run pod install after navigating into ios folder in cmd.
```

now instead,

```
1) Go to your project's home dir using cmd. 
2) run npm install 
3) Thereafter run rnpm link or react-native link 
4) see ios folder in your project folder and if you find any pod file then run pod install after navigating into ios folder in cmd.
```

Comment: Why do you explain the same steps twice?

Comment: Same post twice

Answer (score 6):

When you've installed a library with native content(android or ios) then you need to require linking to the component react-native library.
like this

```
react-native link react-native-sound-player
```

Answer (score 2):

When you installed any third party library with native content,you have to link the dependencies in android and ios. react-native link is responsible for including the dependencies in gradlew and pod files.

for suppose you installed react-native-vector-icons package then you have to link in your gradlew files. the new version of react native 0.60 has auto linking.

> **npm install react-native-vector-icons**
>
> **react-native link react-native-vector-icons**

Comment: Thank you @Au Nguyen, I am really new to stack overflow and i really appreciate your effort for editing my post which really help others to understand

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with fonts, `react-native link` is used for linking the fonts and assets to project. `link` command is also for linking the libraries to react-native

But now React-native too better so there is no need to link the library we can use

1. `pos install`
2. `npx jetify`

it will automatically link the libraries

Comment: pod install you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

react-native link is an automatic way for installing native dependencies. It is an alternative to manually linking the dependency in your project. It works for both Android and iOS

Comment: Hello Yeasir! Welcome to StackOverflow. Its great to see you helping out ths community keep it up and rememember, PRO tip: Always try and add references tpo your answers to help you target a wider audience. happy coding