# What is the difference between react-native install vs link?

Tags: react-native

looking at the documentation about these two similar commands:

```
$ react-native link --help
react-native link [options] [packageName]
  links all native dependencies (updates native build files)
```

and

```
$ react-native install  --help

  react-native install [options] <packageName>
  install and link native dependencies
```

I do not understand the difference if we specify the `packageName`. So, what is the difference between `react-native link SOMEPACKAGE` and `react-native install SOMEPACKAGE`?

Comment: The former simply links native dependencies, the latter installs and links. The second example is short hand for `npm install Foo` and `react-native link Foo`.

Comment: @Dan thanks -- feel free to put it as an answer and I'm happy to accept!

Comment: Just updated. Happy to have helped.

Comment: See this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874385/the-use-of-react-native-link-command) for a discussion on what `react-native link` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former simply links native dependencies, the latter installs and links. The second example is short hand for `npm install Foo` and `react-native link Foo`.