# react-native build failed (run-ios)

Tags: react-native

I try to pass from CRNA to React-Native application with native code. When i build with react-native run-ios, the build failed and i don't know what to do!

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

```
CompileC /Users/Karl/Documents/Applications/MyItems51Work/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/raw_logging.o /Users/Karl/Documents/Applications/MyItems51Work/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/src/raw_logging.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyItems.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyItems.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Comment: Do you have any npm modules that requires linking ?

Comment: I don't know, how i can view if module requires linkings?

Comment: react-native-image-picker, need to be linking?

Comment: yes it did require linking according to the documentation  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker

Answer (score 1):

Linking issues is usually misleading, and not easy to debug:

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874385/the-use-of-react-native-link-command) has very good practices to avoid these kind of issues.