# Can i move my node_modules folder to another project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I had some issues with a current iOS React Native project that i spent a long time working on. I've decided to start afresh. However i did spend a lot of time ensuring i got the correct versions of various react native modules and configuring these to work. These sit in my old 'node_modules' folder.

Can i copy these modules/folders (from the old 'node_modules') over to my new project? Do i need to update 'package.json' or link using 'react-native link xxxxx'? It it as simple as that in theory?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem correctly, but theorically all you have to do is copy/paste your package.json in your fresh project and run `npm install`.

Answer (score 10):

You don't *need* to copy over your `node_modules` directory. You *can* if you'd like, but it is not considered best practice. In any case, you shouldn't make any modifications to the files inside `node_modules`.

Preferably you need to only copy over your `package.json` file and optionally, your `package-lock.json` (or `yarn.lock` if you're using Yarn) file so that your project will be easily installable and upgradeable on other computers.

When you have a `package.json` or `package-lock.json` file, you can run `npm install` (or `yarn install`) to install the packages to your `node_modules` directory.

Copying your `package-lock.json` file over as well would ensure that the exact same versions of all of the packages that you have installed in your previous project will be installed in the new project as well. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297803/what-is-the-role-of-the-package-lock-json) for more information on the `package-lock.json` file.

Unfortunately, I don't know much about react-native and linking react-native dependencies, but from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54764060/3486675) it seems that you would have to link any dependencies that contain native code again after you've run `npm install`.

Comment: ok. so i don't need to copy over the package folder, you're saying by copying over my yarn.lock file and running 'yarn add react-native-module-xx' it will fetch and install these?

Comment: If you copy over your `yarn.lock` file with all the dependencies that you need, you only need to run `yarn install` and all of the dependencies will be installed. No need to run `yarn add <package-name>` for each package.

Answer (score 3):

No, I wouldn't recommend you to copy specific module from node_modules folder as once installed it has entries in .bin folder and files which you will miss while copying and it will be of no help in new project as they will be downloaded and installed again due to missing indexes.

Solutions :

- You can use same package.json and package-lock in another project if you are sure that the dependencies version in it are exactly compatible or one you want, and install those dependencies in new project. The package-lock.json will ensure the version you choose.
- Yes you can copy **whole** node_modules (have done it multiple times) from one project to another and use same package.json and package-lock (Will only save time in dependencies installation/download)

**As you are starting fresh** what i will recommend is create a new package.json and copy only those dependencies which are important for the project initialization, and as you progress  add specific dependencies you need while developing. This will save you from huge garbage of unused dependencies which are hard to keep track of once the project inflates.

Comment: Hi Vikas, so my new package.json file is pretty empty, and from my old package.json file, i know i have 8 dependencies to add. So can i copy for example 'react-native-fetch-blob' folder, from the old node_modules to the new node_modules folder and just run 'npm install react-native-fetch-blob'?

Comment: You can copy but it will be of no use, its as simple as copy the package.json entry for "react-native-fetch-blob" and do npm install.
Also you can do "npm install react-native-fetch-blob@<version>" if you want a specific version else latest will be installed.

Comment: Not necessarly, once version are matched then just remove the ^ from the package.json "react-native-fetch-blob" and "react-native" versions. You won't have to link again and again after ever npm install, its all about compatibility. :-)

Comment: right now there's quite a few ^ in the package.json. Should they be removed before the npm install?

Comment: package-lock take cares of this, but if you want to be sure from your side and not sharing the package-lock with other contributors then you should remove the ^ only from the link dependencies. Note : As you progress and decide to upgrade to later version of react then keep in mind that you should update these link manually  and link again (You might want to upgrade later as newer libraries require newer version of framework). ^ just indicates to the npm that install latest/better version if available.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can move it but you can't copy it, at least not with a naive `cp -r`! The node_modules/.bin directory ought to be full of symlinks to scripts in their respective directories in node_moudles, but after a `cp -r` these will be copies, which will now resolve relative module paths incorrectly.

For example, `npm install typescript` installs a executable script with the contents

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../lib/tsc.js')
```

in two locations. Before a copy, that looks like this:

```
$ ls -l node_modules/.bin/tsc node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
-rwxr-xr-x 45 node_modules/.bin/tsc
-rwxr-xr-x 45 node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
```

and after a `cp -r` copy, like this:

```
$ ls -l node_modules/.bin/tsc node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
lrwxr-xr-x 21 node_modules/.bin/tsc -> ../typescript/bin/tsc
-rwxr-xr-x 45 node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
```

which makes the ../typescript/bin/tsc no longer exist, resulting in

```
$ tsc -b
...
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/tsc.js'
...
```