# Can i use native base without installing `react-native link`?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I want to use native-base but i do not want to install react-native link. How can i do this?

The reason i do not want to install react-native link is because react-native doc suggest us to delete react-native CLI globally.

Comment: For rn 0.60+ just install native base, don't need react native link, it ia automatic

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have misunderstanding of what `react-native link` does. `react-native link` is an automatic way for installing native dependencies. [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874385/what-is-react-native-link)

In case of Native Base. This library is consist of other npm packages, so you need to install them in order to work properly with Native Base.

Native Base Docs states

*Install Peer Dependencies
The peer dependencies included from any npm packages does not automatically get installed. Your application will not depend on it explicitly.* [read more here](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your react-native version is 0.60+ you do not need to link dependencies. All you need to do is install dependencies and you are good to do.