# Unrecognized font family - custom fonts in react native

Tags: react-native, fonts

Error: "Unrecognized font family"

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my custom fonts are not being recognized.

I have done the following:

1. Add custom font files in assets/fonts folder. I tried multiple different fonts.
2. Create react-native.config.js file with "assets": ['./assets/fonts']
3. Pod deintegrate / pod install
4. npx react-native-asset
5. Update the plist values in xcode to point to the fonts

*I am running react-native 0.71.5

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to link your assets ?

```
npx react-native link 

npx react-native-asset
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like that command has been automatically integrated as of 0.60.0.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874385/what-is-react-native-link